# Document.write only overwrites the page once

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I've been using `document.write()` to replace existing html with some loaded by AJAX.
If used once per normal load it works fine (by normal I mean without AJAX), but if used more than once, it writes without replacing the existing content

In other words, the first time `document.write()` is called on page1, page1 is overwritten (as intended) but the next time it's called, the new content is **appended** to page1. Why?

Here's some code to reproduce my issue:

Global JavaScript (on all pages):

```
function loadXMLDoc(name) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", transferComplete, false);
    xmlhttp.open("GET", name, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    function transferComplete() {
        document.write(xmlhttp.responseText);
        history.replaceState(null, null, name);
    }
}
```

Page one:

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadXMLDoc('page2.html');">p1</a>
```

Page two:

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadXMLDoc('page3.html');">p1</a>
```

Page three:

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadXMLDoc('page1.html');">p1</a>
```

Comment: Can we see some code please?

Comment: You'd better use `$(document).html(...);` than `document.write()`

Comment: You should not be using `document.write` for stuff like that. Or for any kind of stuff really.

Comment: As mentioned in an answer you issue is you need to use document.close() to finish the document.write() However document.write is never to be used in the same window as the script unless it is inline and not after the page has finished loading since it WIPES the page it is on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the expected behaviour. The `write` method is used to write content into the page when it is rendering.

It only replaces the page when it's used after the page has completed, because the first time that you use it, it will do an implicit `document.open()` to start a new stream to write to.

To use it properly to replace the page, call `document.open` first, then use `document.write` one or more times to write the content, then call `document.close` to tell the browser that the new page is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Call `document.close()` after you've written to it following an ajax update.

It's worth pointing out that if you're replacing the entire document with the result of an ajax response, it's hard to see any advantage of introducing that complexity over simply posting a plain old `<form>` or traversing an `<a>` link.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using `document.write` because, when I use `document.body.innerHTML` to replace the body only (or some other part) it takes time for everything to look right. It looks like the browser is rendering everything in front of the user's eyes, and that's not half-pleasant

Comment: @user3088260 it's going to take time to reload the entire page too.

Comment: that's not what I mean, have a look at [this](http://www.cryptolight.cf) and try clicking on a link. the page sort of rearranges itself weirdly..

Comment: @user3088260 the advantage of ajax is realized when you only update the smallest portion of the page necessary. If you're updating the entire page, you might as well use something simpler like plain links or forms, because that's what they do - replace the entire page.

Comment: What about JavaScript? If I use `innerHTML` javascript won't execute right?